# How do I get Ansible to ping other AWS servers?

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using RHEL 7.x as my control server.  I have installed Ansible 2.2.2.0.  The managed nodes are running CentOS 6.  I cannot upgrade Ansible because of an incompatibility.

Without Ansible, I can ping the managed servers from the control server.  From the control server I can SSH to the managed nodes without password authentication.  With Ansible from the control server, I cannot ping the managed servers.  Why cannot I use basic Ansible operations (e.g., ansible -m ping all)?

Here are some details.  As root, I run this:

```
ansible -m ping all -vvvv
```

I saw this:

> | UNREACHABLE! => {
>       "changed": false,
>       "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data
>   /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying
>   options for *\r\npercent_expand: unknown key %C\r\n",
>       "unreachable": true

So I rebooted.

I tried it again.  I saw this:

> [WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [x.y.z.z]. Use
>   ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
>
> x.y.z.z | FAILED! => {
>       "failed": true,
>       "msg": "failed to transfer file to Please login as the user \"centos\" rather than the user \"root\"./ping.py:\n\nExecuting:
>   program /usr/bin/ssh host x.y.z.z, user (unspecified), command scp -v
>   -t 'Please login as the user \"centos\" rather than the user \"root\"./ping.py'\nOpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb
>   2013\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data
>   /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying
>   options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2:
>   fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master
>   version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0
>   local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session:
>   entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3:
>   mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 10256\r\ndebug3:
>   mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1:
>   mux_client_request_session: master session id: 4\r\nPlease login as
>   the user \"centos\" rather than the user \"root\".\n" }  [WARNING]:
>   scp transfer mechanism failed on [z.x.y.w]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see
>   detailed information
>
> z.x.y.w | FAILED! => {
>       "failed": true,
>       "msg": "failed to transfer file to Please login as the user \"centos\" rather than the user \"root\"./ping.py:\n\nExecuting:
>   program /usr/bin/ssh host z.x.y.w, user (unspecified), command scp -v
>   -t 'Please login as the user \"centos\" rather than the user \"root\"./ping.py'\nOpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb
>   2013\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data
>   /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying
>   options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2:
>   fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master
>   version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0
>   local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session:
>   entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3:
>   mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 10259\r\ndebug3:
>   mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1:
>   mux_client_request_session: master session id: 4\r\nPlease login as
>   the user \"centos\" rather than the user \"root\".\n" }

I then assumed the Linux user "centos" (`su centos`).  I then tried the ansible commands again.  I ran this command:

> ansible -m ping all -vvvv

I saw this:

> x.y.z.z | UNREACHABLE! => {
>       "changed": false,
>       "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e
>   -fips 11 Feb 2013\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\nd
>   ebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1:
>   auto-mux:
>   Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket
>   \"/home/centos/.ansible/cp/ansi
>   ble-ssh-x.y.z.z-22-centos\" does not exist\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect:
>   needpri
>   v 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to x.y.z.z [x.y.z.z] port 22.\r\ndebug2: f
>   d 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1:

... partially removed because it "looked like spam"

> est\r\ndebug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply\r\ndebug1:
>   Authenticat
>   ions that can continue:
>   publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic\r\ndebug1: Trying
>   private key: /home/centos/.ssh/id_dsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity:
>   /home/centos
>   /.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key:
>   /home/cen
>   tos/.ssh/id_ecdsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity:
>   /home/centos/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No su
>   ch file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key:
>   /home/centos/.ssh/id_ed25519
>   \r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/centos/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such
>   file or dire
>   ctory\r\ndebug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\r\ndebug1:
>   No more aut
>   hentication methods to try.\r\nPermission denied
>   (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-
>   with-mic).\r\n",
>       "unreachable": true }

My ansible.cfg file looks like this:

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
library = ../extra_modules
roles_path = ../roles
pipelining = True
remote_user = centos
forks = 20
log_path = ./ansible.log


[ssh_connection]
control_path = ~/.ssh/ansible-ssh-%%C
```

What is wrong?  Why cannot I ping Ansible managed nodes?

Comment: please let me know if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please share your `Ansible hosts/inventory` file and`.ssh folder (ls ~/.ssh)`?

Also please try do to something like that and passing the ssh private key and the user name variables via cli:

ansiblie.cfg

```
[ssh_connection]
pipelining = True
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30m -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
control_path = /tmp/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r
```

command:

```
ansible -m ping all -i <inventory_file> --private-key=~/.ssh/<your pem key.pem> -u <login user ubuntu/centos>
```

Comment: The control_path stanza was the problem.